# Adding a Top Navigation Bar in Windows 8 - Tutorial Issue

Tags: c#, windows-8, visual-studio-2012

I am trying out a [tutorial](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj215600.aspx) on WIndows 8. I need to add a `Navigation Bar`. The steps are given below;

The following is from the tutorial.

1. In Solution Explorer, double-click MainPage.xaml to open it.
2. In the Document Outline, select the "pageRoot" element.
3. In the Properties panel, click the Properties button () to show the Properties view.
4. Under Common in the Properties panel, find the TopAppBar property.
5. Click the New button next to TopAppBar. An AppBar control is added to the page.
6. In the Document Outline, expand the TopAppBar property.
7. Select the "photoPageButton" element, drag it onto the AppBar, and drop it.
8. Under Layout in the Properties panel, set the HorizontalAlignment property to Right ().
9. Press F5 to build and run the app. To test the app bar, right-click on the main page. The app bar opens at the top of the screen.

I Double-clicked on the `MainPage.xaml`, and then in the `Document Outline` i selected `pageRoot`. and in the `properties` Window expanded `Common` and i clicked on `New` next to `TopAppBar`.

It added several other `Fields` below it. `Allow Drop`, `Background` and `Cache Mode` are some of it. Then in the `Document Outline` i dragged the button to the `AppBar` under `TopAddBar`. Changed the `HorizontalAlignment` to `Right`, build and executed the application. But i don't see the button added to the top Navigation bar. What have i done wrong here ?

UPDATE

```
<Page.Resources>

    <!-- TODO: Delete this line if the key AppName is declared in App.xaml -->
    <x:String x:Key="AppName">My Application</x:String>
</Page.Resources>
<common:LayoutAwarePage.TopAppBar>
    <AppBar Background="#E5A41D1D" AllowDrop="True" BorderBrush="#E5C5A7A7" HorizontalAlignment="Right">
        <Button Content="Next Page&#xD;&#xA;" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Width="230" Height="70" Background="#FF12668D" FontFamily="Shruti" FontSize="36" Click="Button_Click_2"/>
    </AppBar>
</common:LayoutAwarePage.TopAppBar>

<!--
    This grid acts as a root panel for the page that defines two rows:
    * Row 0 contains the back button and page title
    * Row 1 contains the rest of the page layout
-->
<Grid Style="{StaticResource LayoutRootStyle}" Background="#FF282D40">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="140"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <!-- Back button and page title -->

    <!-- Back button and page title -->
    <!-- Back button and page title -->
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Button x:Name="backButton" Click="GoBack" IsEnabled="{Binding Frame.CanGoBack, ElementName=pageRoot}" Style="{StaticResource BackButtonStyle}"/>
        <TextBlock x:Name="pageTitle" Grid.Column="1" Text="Welcome !!! " Style="{StaticResource PageHeaderTextStyle}" Foreground="#DE2374AC"/>
    </Grid>

    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>

        <!-- Visual states reflect the application's view state -->
        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="ApplicationViewStates">
            <VisualState x:Name="FullScreenLandscape"/>
            <VisualState x:Name="Filled"/>

            <!-- The entire page respects the narrower 100-pixel margin convention for portrait -->
            <VisualState x:Name="FullScreenPortrait">
                <Storyboard>
                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="backButton" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Style">
                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource PortraitBackButtonStyle}"/>
                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                </Storyboard>
            </VisualState>

            <!-- The back button and title have different styles when snapped -->
            <VisualState x:Name="Snapped">
                <Storyboard>
                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="backButton" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Style">
                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource SnappedBackButtonStyle}"/>
                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="pageTitle" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Style">
                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource SnappedPageHeaderTextStyle}"/>
                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                </Storyboard>
            </VisualState>
        </VisualStateGroup>
    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Can you post the generated xaml?

Comment: I have updated my post with the xaml.

Comment: what are you seeing when you right-mouse-click or hit Windows-Z to bring up the app bar - is it there, but empty or does it not appear at all?  FWIW, your markup works fine for me.

Comment: When i R-CLick it appears. Is it how its suppose to work? Sorry but i am new to Windows development

Comment: yes, that's how it works.  The App Bar is "chrome" so will typically not be displayed until you invoke it - by swiping down from top/up from bottom or using the right mouse button or WIndows-Z on the keyboard.  You can make the App Bar 'sticky' via code, but you should have a good reason to do so, not just as a matter of course.  Sounds like you had it right all along! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're following [this tutorial here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj215600.aspx), correct?  It looks like you've dragged the wrong button to your TopAppBar.

The button you should be dragging is named photoPageButton (its x:Name attribute).  Instead, the button you've got in your TopAppBar doesn't have a name, and presents the text "Next Page".

Your XAML markup for the TopAppBar should look something like this after you've dragged the photoPageButton to the TopAppBar:

```
<common:LayoutAwarePage.TopAppBar>
    <AppBar HorizontalAlignment="Right">
        <Button x:Name="photoPageButton" Content="Go to photo page"/>
    </AppBar>
</common:LayoutAwarePage.TopAppBar>
```

After you get a little farther in the tutorial and apply a style to the button, your markup for the TopAppBar will then look like this:

```
<common:LayoutAwarePage.TopAppBar>
    <AppBar HorizontalAlignment="Right">
        <Button x:Name="photoPageButton" 
            Click="photoPageButton_Click"
            HorizontalAlignment="Right" 
            Style="{StaticResource PicturesAppBarButtonStyle}"/>
    </AppBar>
</common:LayoutAwarePage.TopAppBar>
```

It's perfectly acceptable to have the other AppBar settings in there as well - Background, BorderBrush; these are harmless changes to the color - and AllowDrop defaults to true, I believe, so that's fine too.

Comment: According to @JimO'Neil comment above my code works. Do you also think the same or is it still wrong and i have to do something about it?

Comment: Certainly, your code "works": it compiles, runs and the app bar appears with a button... however, the button displayed is not the button the tutorial asks the reader to place there.